# Editing mutiple lines XML in powershell

Tags: xml, windows, powershell, automation

I am looking to change the xml file contents using powershell

I am attempting to change the value for controller host & account name.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding- "utf-8"?>
<appsync-agentxmlns:xsd=http://www.w3.org/XMLSchemaxmlns:xsi=http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-
instance>
«controller host="123.123.123" port="443" ss|="true" enable_tIs12= "true">
‹application name-"Test123"/>
<account name= "customer1" password="/>
</controller>
«machine-agent/>
<app-agents>
<|IS/>
‹standalone-applications>
«standalone-application executable="C:Test\Play.exe">
<tier name= "PlayHouse"/>
</standalone-application>
</standalone-applications>
</app-agents>
</appsync-agent>
```

what i have so far

```
$xmlFile = "C:\temp\config.xml"
$configXml = [xml](gc $xmlFile)
$configXml.SelectSingleNode("//account name='customer1']")account name= customer100
$configXml.SelectSingleNode("//controller host='123.123.123']")controller host= 456.456.456
$configxml.Save($xmlFile)
```

Comment: The provided is not a valid xml, please edit your question and provided the correct one

Answer (score 0):

Your sample xml is still not well formed, but assuming it's fixed along the lines of the code below, and namespaces are properly taken into account, you can achieve your desired output (or something close enough) like this:

```
#your sample xml, fixed as I understand it
$configXml = [xml]@"
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<appsync-agent xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <controller host="123.123.123" port="443" ss="true" enable_tIs12="true">
      ‹application name-"Test123"/&gt;
      <account name="customer1" password="" />
   </controller>
   <machine-agent />
   <app-agents>
      <is />
      ‹standalone-applications&gt;
      <standalone-application executable="C:Test\Play.exe">
         <tier name="PlayHouse" />
      </standalone-application>
      ‹/standalone-applications&gt;
   </app-agents>
</appsync-agent>
"@

#declare the namespace
$ns = New-Object System.Xml.XmlNamespaceManager($xmlFile.NameTable)
$ns.AddNamespace("xsd", "http://www.w3.org/XMLSchema")

#find your data and modify it - note that an attribute name must be preceded with a "@"
$target = $configXml.SelectSingleNode('//account[@name="customer1"]',$ns)
$target.SetAttribute("name", "customer100");

$target2 = $configXml.SelectSingleNode("//controller[@host='123.123.123']",$ns)
$target2.SetAttribute("controller", "456.456.456");
```

Comment: When attempting to run the ps script provided it returns these errors 
+ $n = New-Object .System. Xml.Xm1NamespaceManager ($xm]File. NameTable)
+ CategoryInfo
ObjectNotFound: (:) [New-Object], P5ArgumentException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotFindAppropriateCtor,Microsoft. PowerShell. Commands. NewobjectCommand
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:5 char:1
+
Sns.AddNamespace("xsd".
"http://www.w3.org/XMLSchema")
+ CategoryInfo
Invalidoperation: (:) [], RuntimeException